# Write to XML file using existing dataset created in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, ado.net

Please bear with me. I don't have any knowledge of C# or Visual Basic but I've been tasked with a complex project that wasn't properly scoped.  This is way outside the scope of my normal work but no one in the organization appears to have this knowledge so I'm trying to assist since this data is a state requirement.  I have been googling, watching tutorials, and testing things out for weeks.

I have multiple tables that I've used to create a dataset using Visual Studio 2019. Now I need to write the data in that dataset to XML.  Most of what I've seen online just has a few lines of code like:

```
private void WriteXmlToFile(DataSet thisDataSet)
{
if (thisDataSet == null) { return; }

// Create a file name to write to.
string filename = "XmlDoc.xml";

// Write to the file with the WriteXml method.
thisDataSet.WriteXml(filename);
}
```

or

```
string filePath = "ENTER A VALID FILEPATH";
northwindDataSet.WriteXml(filePath);
```

but doesn't really say where or how they should be utilized (there obviously has to be more to it).  I did try this by replacing 'thisDataSet' with my existing dataset but got an error that the modifier private is not valid for this item.  I think because it's inside of another private void for the button click.

I found a tutorial that helped me create a form and then code for creating and filling a dataset and then writing that to XML and I was able to do that successfully and I understand what is being done.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NEMSIS_Project
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Age");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Gender");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);

        dt.Rows.Add("Mourya", "25", "Male");
        dt.Rows.Add("Steve", "40", "Male");
        dt.Rows.Add("Jasmine", "19", "Female");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        ds.WriteXml("Contacts.xml");

    }
}
}
```

My disconnect is how to use my own dataset.  I've tried piecing together code from around the internet but I keep getting different errors depending on the code.  I've tried searching my issue/question different ways but have yet to come up with anything.  I'm not sure if I need to write something to call my dataset or if I have to "write" a query to pull the data from my dataset into a new dataset and then write to XML.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This Line -> `DataSet ds = new DataSet();` is the key, if you have variable with a DataSet ready change it to `DataSet ds = your_variable_with_dataset;` If your Dataset isnt inside a variable How is your Dataset stored?

Comment: Is your question how to fill the dataset with data from a database?

Comment: @J.Salas That's the piece I don't understand.  What to do with my dataset once it's created.  Do I have to run /compile it?  Right now it's just showing in the Solution Explorer as DataSet.xsd.  I will go out and search around the variable piece to see if I can understand that piece.  Thanks

Comment: @Crowcoder if I understand correctly, I used the wizard to create the dataset so I think it's already filled?  I connected to my database and selected tables and fields and the dataset.xsd was created.

Comment: xsd files only contains the schema of your dataSet not the data inside it. You need to connect to the database fill a dataset from it and THEN use the WriteXml function.
Read about [ADO.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview) or [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) To help you a little more we need some information about the concrete estructure an model of the database which contains the data you want to export to xml

Comment: @J.Salas I wanted to come back and take a moment to thank you for steering me in the right direction. Using the links you provided I was able to create, fill, and write to xml a very basic dataset and it's very promising for what I need. Thank you again for taking time to respond. Much appreciated.